# Avoid false positive detection of our Installer as malware

Tags: installshield, virus-scanning

We're developing an application, which has been around for many years and comes with an Installshield Installer. Recently, virustotal shows that our latest, already released installer is detected by 2 (Kaspersky and ZoneAlarm by Check Point) out of 69 AV-Engines with `Backdoor.Win32.Agent.myuomn`.

The previous installer, build 3 days prior, is not flagged as malicious, and as i've developed this application since the very beginning, i'm pretty sure that this is a false positive. I've checked the changes between the previous installer and the false positive one, and the only change is a PDF that has been changed.

I assume that the change in the file resulted in some signature that both AV engines match with the trojan.

Nevertheless, the concerns arise in our management and the customer that reported this incident, so i got two questions:

1. **How to avoid being flagged as false positive in the future?** I've seen that virustotal offers an API and i thought about uploading the artifacts from azure devops in our pipeline and check the results. At least i'd get a indication at that given point in time, knowing that the AV engines can be later on updated and still flag our product as false positive in the future.
2. **Is there any way to get more details, what exactly kaspersky things why my product is infected?** Although i assume that this won't change much, as the installer is packed itself, but just out of curiosity.

Answer (score 1):

False positive detections from antivirus vendors (AV) are a big headache for many software vendors.

From [our experience](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/antivirus-whitelisting.html) there is no clear solution. We need to constantly adapt our development and deployment processes because AV vendors keep changing their detection heuristics.

We [recommend our users](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/antivirus-whitelisting.html) scanning each release against VirusTotal and submit a takedown request for the vendors that incorrectly flag them. Of course, digital signing helps a lot and should be a default, but it's not enough in some cases.